# Finding the cardinality of Ai and summation

Tags: combinatorics, summation

> Let A = {1, 2, 3,..., n} (i.e. a set with n elements). Recall that a permutation z is an invertible function. Let Sn denote the set of all permutations on A.
>
> Let Ai = {z ∈ Sn | z(i) = i},
> where
> i = 1,...,n.
>
> That is, Ai consists of all the permutations that fix the i-th element of A.
>
> (a) Find |Ai|
>
> (b) Find  $$S_1 = \sum_{i=1}^n |A_i|$$

For (a) I got the cardinality to be n! because the i-th element is fixed but I'm not too sure about this.

So for (b) would I be doing the summation of n!?

Comment: There are $n!$ permutations of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ and not all of those fix the $i$'th element so we know there must be strictly less than $n!$.  How much less?  Try applying the multiplication principle.

Comment: Also what is $A_0$?  Your set $A$ doesn't have an element zero, so either you made a mistake and want $A=\{\color{red}{0},1,2,\dots,n\}$ you want $A=\{\color{red}{0},1,2,\dots,n-1\}$ or you want to find $\sum\limits_{i=\color{red}{1}}^n |A_i|$ for the second part

Comment: oh yeah i made a typo with using mathjax i have fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close, but $|A_i| = (n-1)!$ since the $i -th$ element is fixed (since we can think of this as the permutation group acting on $(n-1)$ elements).

Then $\sum_{i=1}^n |A_i| = \sum_{i=1}^n (n-1)! = n\cdot ((n-1)!) = n!$